# ATL GUI Creator Tool

Tags: user-interface, atl

Is there some kind of tool for creating user interfaces using ATL for C/C++? Like the UI Creator of Visual Studio.

I can't find the components I look for, so I need some sort of list about ATL components. Or, simply some sort of UI creator that I can drag & drop components like text boxes or buttons from toolbox to my project.

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found RC editor in Visual Studio 2010. I'm not sure how I found it, but it magically popped out. I guess I have to sleep some.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, I would create your libraries in c++ and make your GUI in c#.

Comment: Take a look at http://embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder, I havnt used it but looks interesting